The Instagram API is returning no comments data for the specified post
I am testing this code to retrieve comments for a post that has 6 comments, but it returns an empty array for the comments data from Instagram API.
$postId = '18444882094010647'; //https://www.instagram.com/p/C9efIjby2Xy/
$commentUrl = "https://graph.instagram.com/$postId/comments?access_token=$access_token";
$comments = json_decode(file_get_contents($commentUrl), true);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($comments);
echo '</pre>';

Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
        )

    [paging] => Array
        (
            [cursors] => Array
                (
                    [before] => QVFIUkZA2aHZAIak5WeDNpcmNyZAVdYUDdNbVBpVlJkSDVoME44djB4cGw0dHljdHVZARmY5Y3FKV2JtaDFWOVdfeHZA4YlZAjTmhhTGU0UWtPVnJPSnh5Yl9rem9R
                    [after] => QVFIUllsMEV3anRzVE1ZAUHM1YnNUcENkaThUY0w0bUlrOUpieXBTMzR2NGZACOW5LUG9xN3F4Nmp4T2lmajhKZA1FIUmhqbWhUY1pWUHJfSTZASU1FwMkdQa2d3
                )

        )

)

What might I be doing wrong here? The access token has both instagram_business_basic and instagram_business_manage_comments permissions. I am using Instagram API with Instagram Login.
I checked the paging, but there were no results. I also regenerated the access token and confirmed there are no API call limits.

Your application is in development mode, which is preventing you from accessing live data such as comments. Switch to live mode by specifying the privacy policy link in your app settings.
Go to your apps

Once you have navigated to your application, click Basic App Settings

Then write the app policy link (make sure the link is correct, I tried with 404 - doesn't work)

Save your changes with the right button at the bottom

And toggle to live mode

I spent about a month trying to solve this problem and finally found a solution that works. I'm confident it will help you too!

It worked, thank you!

thank you! Just to add that if you're only getting comment ID's returned in the response, it's not documented at all but you do need to use field expansion to get most of the comment data, similar to their other endpoints.
The example here in the docs would actually only return the ID for the comments. Instead the request would be
curl -X GET "https://graph.instagram.com/v21.0/<IG_MEDIA_ID>/comments?fields=id,text,timestamp" to actually get the data

Thanks you saved my day, I was struggling to get this from past 1 week
